# How to parse OS version name into Version class

Tags: c#, version

I am having OS version string like:

`Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1`
`Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3`
`Microsoft Windows Storage Server 2008 R2 Essentials 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1`

How could I parse those string values into [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string with a space a get the string version:

```
        string Os = "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1";
        string[] splitOs = Os.Split(null);

        foreach (var item in splitOs)
        {
            if (item.Contains("."))
            {
                Version v1 = new Version(item)
            }
        }
```